# How to call a method from API Controller using ajax

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

[image]I want to call a method from API Controller using AJAX.  I have tried the following

I have added one hidden field in the view (like what we are doing in mvc controller)

```
<input type="hidden" id="GetShoppingCartUrl" value="@Html.Action("GetShoppingCartUrl","Cart")"/>
```

Then I have written ajax

```
function GetShoppingCart() {
            debugger;
            var url = $('#GetShoppingCartUrl').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        }
```

But here it is not getting the method, **GetShoppingCartUrl**  from the API Controller **CartController**. I want to call that method, what changes make it happening ?

Comment: is the `getShoppingCart` method getting called? Also you don't really need to save the url in the hidden input. You can just directly call it based on your mapping.

Comment: Firstly its `value="@Url.Action(...)` (not `@Html.Action()`) - but use a `data-` attribute, not a hidden input or just include it in the function - var url = '@Url.Action(..);` if the script is not in an external file

Comment: @serendipity method is not hitting.

Comment: @AverlaTeam then call the method.. `GetShoppignCart()` And as I already said just directly map the `url`. `/api/controllerName/methodName/id` unless you've changed it

Comment: @serendipity I have tried that too

Comment: @AverlaTeam what does your route template look like

Comment: @AverlaTeam inside WebApiConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
 function GetShoppingCart() {
                debugger;
                var url = "Cart/GetShoppingCartUrl"
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
            }
```

you can directly put your actionlink in the url 
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: its not working because in mvc controller we can use this method, but in my case it is API controller

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to get the url of your site in javascript and append it before the url in ajax call. e.g  var url = baseUrl+ "Cart/GetShoppingCartUrl";

@{
            string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
    if(url[url.Length-1]!='/')
            {
                url =url+ "/";
            }

    }
        var baseUrl = '@url';
        //alert(baseUrl);